# Allowing Add/Delete/Update of features (web application): OpenLayers + WFS and GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet

I've developed a WPF application that has a custom SQL Server database and uses the Esri ArcGIS WPF API to allow users to view, edit and query shapes (features) on a custom map. Maps are created from tiles using the Bing (Quadkey) system. Users can also create multiple layers. This application has a great focus on the editing aspect. Although I use the ArcGIS WPF API from Esri, there are no other services/servers from this company being used for this solution. Layers, features and symbols are stored using custom structures.

But now I'm looking to make the transition to a web application. I've studied and tested different mapping libraries: Leaflet, OpenLayers, Google Maps API, ArcGIS JavaScript API, etc. I know about WMS/WFS and mapping servers like GeoServer and MapServer (but I don't know what would be the best match).

So, finally, my question: what would be the "best" (recommended) solution for a web application using custom (tile) maps that should have a great experience to allow users to add/delete/delete features, query, filter and save them? I know that the "best" solution can vary greatly. But what I'm really looking for is some advice from experience users that have done this.

**OpenLayers + WFS and GeoServer** would be a good match?

Comment: To the previous combination I would add PostGIS (http://goo.gl/rdsdT). Add/Delete/Update of features require transactional WFS (WFS-T), and GeoServer demands a PostGIS database for running a WFS-T service.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Any mapping server that supports SQL Server and its spatial data?

Comment: I'm using a OpenStreetMap in background with PostGIS to store my data and OpenLayers to show. CRUD is making over AJAX.